# Como fazer uma DIV da esquerda ter a mesma altura de uma grande DIV à direita?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, height

Tenho uma página do tipo one-page com 3 colunas. A coluna central possui o conteúdo do site. E as colunas da direita e da esquerda precisam repetir uma imagem verticalmente por toda a altura da página.

```
<body id="home" class="homepage">
<div class="container col-sm-1 col-md-1" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/30x30');
    background-repeat:repeat-y;">
    </div>

    <div class="container col-sm-10 col-md-10">Conteúdo Enorme</div>

    <div class="container col-sm-1 col-md-1" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/30x30')>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**Como faço as colunas laterais acompanharem a altura da coluna central, sem perder a responsividade?**

Answer (score 0):

Você pode definir o imagem como background do `<body>` dessa forma não precisa das comunas laterais, basta definir a largura da div com o conteúdo como sendo menor do que o da pagina tipo 70vw e `margin: auto`, assim ela vai para o centro horizontal da pagina.

Comment: Nesse caso seria muto dificil acertar a largura da imagem lateral... a ideia doida que me pediram pra executar é colocar este padrão nas laterais (veja:  https://i.pinimg.com/originals/07/0a/ea/070aea5a0cab75ccf767a0a1f233b81e.jpg) uma unica coluna de cada lado do site, repetindo verticalmente apenas, não horizontalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Seu código tem vários "problemas" pois seu Grid está longe do que diz a documentação oficial....

Primeiro que vc tem que colocar o seu conteúdo dentro de um único `container`, depois que o filho desse `container` deve ser uma `.ROW` e ai sim vc divida as `colunas col-` do seu grid em `1-10-1`

Depois basta vc colocar uma classe por exemplo na coluna da direita e da esquerda e nelas colocar seu `background-image`. Dessa forma independente do camanho do conteúdo o BG das colunas laterais sempre vai ser do tamanho da coluna do meio

Veja um exemplo

```css
.bg {
    background-image: url(https://png.pngtree.com/element_pic/00/16/07/115783678b832b9.jpg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 bg"></div>

        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10">
                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus et perspiciatis molestias itaque voluptatum quo cumque laudantium autem ullam beatae. Illo, voluptates? Voluptatem exercitationem, qui iste suscipit vero nesciunt sunt excepturi ipsam nam ullam deserunt labore vitae, est veritatis voluptatum adipisci fuga molestias nostrum sit quod molestiae magni animi! Numquam nisi reiciendis dignissimos! At, delectus labore amet fugit tenetur, sapiente eum animi cum ipsam voluptatum, quibusdam distinctio eius consequatur inventore aspernatur ut soluta numquam magni pariatur error. Maxime dolorum maiores magni, facilis voluptas eum assumenda nihil tempore voluptates dolore odio rerum consequatur excepturi praesentium ut necessitatibus officia iste ullam ipsum animi? Distinctio ducimus reiciendis doloremque ex id? Sed nostrum consequuntur libero laudantium? Hic explicabo ex maxime quasi delectus distinctio. Culpa ipsam tempora esse saepe voluptatem nesciunt, officiis ipsa dignissimos, officia porro architecto reprehenderit molestias possimus nulla velit temporibus labore dolorum. Deserunt, animi pariatur tempora, eos reiciendis labore consequatur aut, similique aspernatur at commodi incidunt quos facilis quasi. Impedit nemo eos cum est labore inventore iusto error odit ratione corporis amet corrupti consectetur molestiae commodi libero nostrum dolores, fugiat, eum ex officiis. Labore consectetur fuga blanditiis nihil, quasi quo incidunt ipsam. Odit aliquid perspiciatis minus esse beatae rerum ipsa maiores? Dolore, amet quidem, tempore modi eaque odio numquam laboriosam quisquam vitae accusantium ducimus maxime dolorem mollitia, soluta quibusdam! Recusandae quam excepturi impedit perspiciatis natus placeat officia officiis saepe? Accusantium rerum distinctio error in minima accusamus impedit possimus, deserunt ad rem assumenda a fuga magnam at nihil numquam ipsum iusto harum soluta recusandae commodi? Beatae impedit ducimus corporis quisquam deserunt incidunt accusantium animi, minima reiciendis veniam vero doloribus ipsam pariatur qui, neque aspernatur, culpa accusamus laborum. Exercitationem id, aliquam possimus accusantium animi molestiae dignissimos veritatis facilis soluta repellat ab adipisci placeat! Dolore, minima laudantium tempore optio inventore ipsam voluptatibus modi ratione fugiat recusandae amet esse! Alias officiis rem provident corrupti quae quia doloremque veniam voluptatem deleniti placeat eveniet 
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 bg"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo! Vou testar e logo te dou um retorno.

Comment: @AlamBique sem problemas jovem, se tiver alguma dúvida é só falar.